# How capture image from several DSLR camera via USB use Python?

Tags: opencv, camera, video-capture, capture, canon-sdk

I need to synchronize and capture image from several(10-20) DSLR(Canon) via USB use Python, but I don't know how.

I got it with `SparkoCam` and this python code, but it work only with one camera

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while True:
    ret,img=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('video output',img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(10)& 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Does anyone knows how can I capture image from DSLR? opencv, sdk?

Comment: I'm not sure OpenCV is the ideal library to use for image acquisition in this case. Did you consider searching for some libraries that are specifically targeted at controlling Canon cameras?

Answer (score 1):

If you are insistent on using opencv for this application, simply modifying your code to use multiple Videocapture objects will work

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2) #you can check what integer code the next camera uses
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2) #you can check what integer code the next camera uses
#and so on for other cameras
#You could also make this more convenient and more readable by using an array of videocapture objects

while True:
    ret1,img1=cap1.read()
    cv2.imshow('video output1',img1)
    ret2,img2=cap2.read()
    cv2.imshow('video output2',img2)
    #and so on for the other cameras
    k=cv2.waitKey(10)& 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
cap1.release()
cap2.release()
#and so on for the other cameras
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```